# Merging one field from a JSON into another JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have two JSON files with a similar structure. I want to take one of the item from the first JSON file and add it into the second JSON file using the `jq` command. I've been trying to do it using `map` and `*` without any success.

I have this file:

```
{
  "items": {
    "foo": {
      "key": "value1"
    },
    "bar": {
      "key": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

And this file:

```
{
  "items": {
    "baz": {
      "key": "value3"
    },
    "qux": {
      "key": "value4"
    }
  }
}
```

And would like to take the first item on the first file and merge it into the second file, in order to get this output:

```
{
  "items": {
    "baz": {
      "key": "value3"
    },
    "qux": {
      "key": "value4"
    },
    "foo": {
      "key": "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_entries[0]` to reduce to the first item, `to_entries` to reconstruct the object, then update the `items` object using `|=`, and use `*` to merge with the second file accessed through `input`:

```sh
jq '(.items |= ([to_entries[0]] | from_entries)) * input' 1.json 2.json
```

```json
{
  "items": {
    "foo": {
      "key": "value1"
    },
    "baz": {
      "key": "value3"
    },
    "qux": {
      "key": "value4"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RZ8tTERcHJ)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That almost solves my problem. What if the item in which I'm interested is in an arbitrary position and I would like to get it by its name (foo in this case)?

Comment: @AAB07 Then use `(.items |= {foo}) * input` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1kkgR0cFOi)

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I'm learning `jq` and bash altogether and sometimes I get stuck in simple things.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
jq '.items.foo = input.items.foo' 2.json 1.json
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sven Viking It's a single assignment....

Comment: Fair, I was clearing out a moderation queue and probably applied this suggestion with too little consideration.